# Setting Margin Properties in code

Tags: c#, wpf, margin

```
MyControl.Margin.Left = 10;
```

Error:

> Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Margin' because it is not a variable

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The problem is that [`Margin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx) is a property, and its type ([`Thickness`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness.aspx)) is a value type. That means when you access the property you're getting a *copy* of the value back.

Even though you *can* change the value of the [`Thickness.Left`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness.left.aspx) property for a particular value (grr... mutable value types shouldn't exist), it wouldn't change the margin.

Instead, you'll need to set the `Margin` property to a new value. For instance (coincidentally the same code as Marc wrote):

```
Thickness margin = MyControl.Margin;
margin.Left = 10;
MyControl.Margin = margin;
```

As a note for library design, I would have vastly preferred it if `Thickness` were immutable, but with methods that returned a new value which was a copy of the original, but with one part replaced. Then you could write:

```
MyControl.Margin = MyControl.Margin.WithLeft(10);
```

No worrying about odd behaviour of mutable value types, nice and readable, all one expression...

Comment: kudos for looking up the actual type... I confess to cheating with `var` - ahem, sorry; I mean "using an appropriate language feature" ;-p

Comment: It helped that the error message contained the fully qualified type name. With a quick bookmark for MSDN, I just needed "msdn System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Margin" on the address bar to get to the right page...

Comment: Marc, zvolkov has discovered our secret! It turned out it was way too easy to get 200 in a day, so I thought I'd set myself more of a challenge and try to get the top 2 users. Getting "Marc" as a moderator was just a bonus... ;)

Comment: But what about the others of us? I mean me? do they know about the "legion" script yet?

Comment: Can I add that you guys are hilarious? Do you work together outside of StackOverflow or something? You're all so chummy - it makes me feel like an outsider, haha.

Comment: having same problem these ages should use "Padding margin = MyControl.Margin;"

Answer (score 45):

The `Margin` property returns a `Thickness` structure, of which `Left` is a property. What the statement does is copying the structure value from the `Margin` property and setting the `Left` property value on the copy. You get an error because the value that you set will not be stored back into the `Margin` property.

(Earlier versions of C# would just let you do it without complaining, causing a lot of questions in newsgroups and forums on why a statement like that had no effect at all...)

To set the property you would need to get the `Thickness` structure from the `Margin` property, set the value and store it back:

```
Thickness m = MyControl.Margin;
m.Left = 10;
MyControl.Margin = m;
```

If you are going to set all the margins, just create a `Thickness` structure and set them all at once:

```
MyControl.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

Comment: `New Thickness` is exactly what I was searching for when wanting to modify both the `Margin` and the `Padding` properties.  I would wager this should work for `BorderThickness` as well. 
 THANKS!!

Answer (score 17):

`Margin` is returning a struct, which means that you are editing a **copy**. You will need something like:

```
var margin = MyControl.Margin;
margin.Left = 10;
MyControl.Margin = margin;
```

Comment: (cheers, fixed some time ago... I expect you needed a page refresh ;-p)

Answer (score 15):

One could simply use this

```
MyControl.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(10, 0, 5, 0);
```

Comment: OP wants to change only one dimension of margin not all...

Comment: @SoftWar that is correct.

Answer (score 4):

One would guess that (and my WPF is a little rusty right now) that Margin takes an object and cannot be directly changed.

e.g

```
MyControl.Margin = new Margin(10,0,0,0);
```

Comment: This does not work: _'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Margin' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'_

Comment: use Thickness in .NetFramework:
MyControl.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);

Answer (score 4):

To use `Thickness` you need to create/change your project `.NET framework` platform version to 4.5. becaus this method available only in version 4.5. (Also you can just download PresentationFramework.dll and give referense to this dll, without create/change your `.NET framework` version to 4.5.)

But if you want to do this simple, You can use this code:

```
MyControl.Margin = new Padding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
```

also

```
MyControl.Margin = new Padding(int all);
```

This is simple and no needs any changes to your project

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the situation, you can also try using padding property here...

```
MyControl.Margin=new Padding(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: More explanation about your code would be nice. Please refrain from just posting code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what are you asking, but to make things comfortable, you can inherit your own Control and add a property with the code that Marc suggests:

```
class MyImage : Image {
    private Thickness thickness;
    public double MarginLeft {
        get { return Margin.Left; }
        set { thickness = Margin; thickness.Left = value; Margin = thickness; }
    }
}
```

Then in the client code you can write just

```
MyImage img = new MyImage();
img.MarginLeft = 10;
MessageBox.Show(img.Margin.Left.ToString()); // or img.MarginLeft
```

Comment: using inheritance to solve such problem? Quite a big overhead, isn't it?

Comment: @LuckyLikey it depends on the use case: if you plan to alter the `MerginLeft` on multiple places in the project, inheritance avoids design problems. Of course, if this is a single place in your project, I would choose the accepted answer.