# Why can I not change the Margin?

Tags: c#, wpf, margin

[image]
On the top it says, "Gets or **sets**...", so then why is it not letting me change it?

Comment: Look at this detailed answer from skeet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003772/setting-margin-properties-in-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this because although `Margin.Left` gets or sets, it's not used like a variable. Just like `Padding`.

As you may notice, `Margin` (as for `Padding`) is a property and `Thickness` is its value. So, when you say

```
label1.Margin.Left = MainGrid.ActualHeight / 2 - label1.ActualHeight / 2;
```

you are only editing a copy *(`Margin`)* because `Margin` returns a struct (`Thickness`) . That's why you receive an error. The changes are not saved because it's a copy!

Basically, although you can change the value of `Object.Margin.Left` to a specific value yet it wouldn't save/change the object `Margin` property and that's why you get an error.

---

### For example

We can NOT say

```
label1.Margin.Left = MainGrid.ActualHeight / 2 - label1.ActualHeight /2;
```

but we can say

```
Thickness NewThickness = new Thickness(); //Initialize a new Thicnkess
NewThickness.Left = MainGrid.ActualHeight / 2 - label1.ActualHeight /2; //Set the left property of NewThickness
label1.Margin = NewThickness; //Apply the changes to label1
```

This means that, because `Margin` is a property, you are not allowed to change its `Thickness` directly.

---

Alternatively, you can use the following which I believe to be easier to set a `Margin` of an object

```
label1.Margin = new Thickness(double left, double top, double right, double bottom);
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all arguments are mandatory for the WPF Margin property, although you may want change just one or two property values a time...

with Google search I saw in Java as well as ASP.net using margin property with all 4 values set.

However this example allows user to retrieve Label.Margin.Left value though...
 http://forums.asp.net/t/1834713.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

The point here is that it makes no sense to assign to a property within a temporary `struct` value, as it has no lasting effect.

[System.Windows.Thickness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness.aspx) is a `struct`, and `label1.Margin` is a *copy* of the `Thickness` value for the margin of `label1`.  It's a copy because `struct`s are passed by value.  There's no point assigning to `label1.Margin.Left` as you will only change the value of `Left` in a copy of `label1.Margin`.

What you can do instead is the following:

```c#
Thickness t = label1.Margin;
t.Left = ......; // assign your value here
label1.Margin = t;
```

See also the [MSDN page for the CS1612 error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wydkhw2c(v=vs.71).aspx).

The tooltip is saying 'Gets or sets...' because you can get or set the `Margin` property of `label1`, but in your specific case there's no point assigning to the `Left` property of `label1.Margin`.