# Label animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, label

I am trying to animate a `Label` in WPF. On a `timer tick`. I am doing it like this:

```
SlideLabel.Margin.Left = 90;
```

But there is an exception:

> Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Margin' because it is not a variable

I got the answer here: [Setting Margin Properties in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003772/setting-margin-properties-in-code)

But I am little bit confuse about one thing, probably because of weak OOP concepts. If I create a new instance of `Thickness` every time like this:

```
SildeLabel.Margin = new Thickness(90, 18, -1, 0);
```

So these all the instances will be in memory and are referenced. So the GC will not dispose them. It will take a lot of memory. Am I correct here?

Actually I want to make a slide at the bottom of the screen like news channels have. So I couldn't find any better to make this. If this is worst, then kindly tell me about any other way to accomplish this.

Comment: You could use Animations instead of a timer

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I am very novice to WPF. Is there any basic or simple article to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `TranslateTransform` with `StoryBoard` to achieve your desired animation.

Please check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746981.aspx) MSDN code example.

Hope it helps.