# How to change rectangle property in its .cs code?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created my own control for WPF and in .cs code I want to define method to change margin parameter.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public String TagName { get; set; }

        public UserControl1(String TagName)
        {
            this.TagName = TagName;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public double TagValue { get; set; }

        public void test(double val) {
            valueRectangle.Margin.Top(10);
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm still getting error while setting any value to Margin.Top

Edit: Errorcode here:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1955  Non-invocable member 'Thickness.Top' cannot be used like a method.  WpfApplication1 X:\07_projects\00_ostatni\CSharp\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\UserControl1.xaml.cs   36  Active

Comment: Is your error `Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Margin' because it is not a variable` ?

Comment: Besides that `Top` is a property, not a method, you should assign a new Thickness like `valueRectangle.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);`

Comment: Read Jon Skeets answer here for why you need to asiggn a new Margin. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003772/setting-margin-properties-in-code ??

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I will use `new Thickness()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Clemens wrote:

> Besides that Top is a property, not a method, you should assign a new
>   Thickness like valueRectangle.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);